# Perl substitute ignore everything between brackets

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string like: `'Hello "Jay" < img src="hello.png">'`

I am extracting the string and escaping double/single quotes using a simple substitute:

```
$string =~ s/\"/\\\"/g;
```

The problem is that I dont want to escape those double quotes inside the  tag

Is there a way ignore all double quotes between <..>

Comment: Is this just an example string but in reality you have larger context with html tags? If so, I recommend using a parser for this.

Comment: @hwnd just an example, and yes i have larger text with html tags. what type or parser are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see if it works for you:

```
s/\"(?![^<>]*>)/\\\"/g;
```

If it doesn't give me a longer input string to test with.

Answer (score -1):

```
s/\"(?![^<>]*>)/\\\"/g
```

`\"` matches double quotes

`(?![^<>]*>)` negative lookahead, implies that it will not match anything within `[^<>]*`